# HttpWebRequest hanging on third call

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a method which I am using to login to a website. Each time, this method creates a new Webrequest and Webresponse, it works fine for the first 2 times. However, the third time I call it, it hangs (On the line `using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())`). I don't know why. I am disposing everything.  Here is my method:

```
public static void Login()
{
    //Create HTTP request
    HttpWebRequest request =
        WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://www.mcgamerzone.com/login?username=username&url=/settings/security");

    //Set request headers
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection {
        {"Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
    };

    //Post data
    Dictionary<string, string> postDict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"login", "Login"},
        {"password", "password"},
        {"username", "username"}
    };

    //Post data as byte array
    byte[] postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postDict).ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    //Write post data to request stream
    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
}
```

Then use it like this in a console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Login();
    Console.WriteLine("Logged in");

    Login();
    Console.WriteLine("Logged in");

    Login();
    Console.WriteLine("Logged in");
}
```

"Logged in" appears 2 times in the console. It takes about 3 mins for the third one to appear.
I cant figure out the reason why it is hanging. Certainly its not due to not disposing the objects properly because I am creating a new object each time. Wireshark shows that it's not sending information to server and server is not sending either.

Comment: do you see it write 'Logged in' the second time? Also, in your code, is 'SetCookie' supposed to be 'GetCookie'? You mention a `GetCookie` method but i don't see one in your code.

Comment: You don't need to add cookies from the response to the cookiecontainer, that happens automatically

Comment: DrewJordan, yes. "Logged in" is written the second time and the third one takes ages (Like 1-2 mins) to get written. I have fixed the type, it's supposed to be `SetCookie` yes.
rene, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I have edited my question, now it's just a method. :) Can you see if it works for you? Maybe it's my firewall?

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem. For 3 device keys, the 3rd hangs or (if set to) times out.